# An Inequality of Expectation of Logarithm

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me showing that the following inequality is true or not?

$$E\left[\big(\log(1+X)\big)^2\right] \leq \big(E[X]\big)^2$$

Comment: Does [.] represent gif

Comment: What have you attempted? People will be more keen to help if you show your work.

Comment: I am reading a paper in which there is a proof related to that inequality and I am not convinced.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the natural logarithm, but the argument works for any other basis. Take the random variable $X=-\frac{1}{2}$. Then $$E\big[\big(\log(1+X)\big)^2\big] = E\Big[\Big(\log\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2\Big] \approx 0.48.  $$

On the other hand, $$\Big( E[X] \Big)^2 = \Big( E\Big[-\frac{1}{2}\Big] \Big)^2 = 0.25. $$

We conclude that $$ E\left[\big(\log(1+X)\big)^2\right] > \big(E[X]\big)^2. $$

If you want this inequality to be true, it is necessary to consider more specific kind of random variables. In general the inequality is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer of [Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33688/integral).
If it is supposed that $X\geq 0$ a.s., then the inequality is true. 
Indeed, function $g(x)=\log^2(1+x)$ is concave for $x>0$, and Jensen inequality give
$$
E\log^2(1+X)=\color{red}{Eg(X)\leq g(EX)} = \log^2(1+EX) \leq (EX)^2$$
since $\log(1+x)\leq x$.

Comment: I appreciate this one since it is actually the case that the random variable X is assumed to be positive almost surely.